# Dynamics CRM 2011 Entities

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

I am very new to Dynamics CRM, and starting to learn how to develop Custom Applications that use the CRM Web Services.

I have the Dynamics CRM SDK and I started with the Labs that Microsoft provides, so I now have a small testing application that can list Organizations of a user that has logged in.

This test application can create new account records, but what I am actually interested is accessing the incedent entity.

I have the following

```
Entity location1 = new Entity("account");
location1["name"] = LocationName.Text;
location1.Id = this.OrgService.Create(location1);
MessageBox.Show("New Location ID is " + location1.Id.ToString());
```

But what I really want to do is something in the line of

```
Entity location1 = new Entity("incedent");
location1["title"] = LocationName.Text;
location1.Id = this.OrgService.Create(location1);
MessageBox.Show("New Location ID is " + location1.Id.ToString());
```

But I get an exception stating that there is no such entity, yet when I log onto the CRM through IE I can create a case with no issues.

I am assuming my approach is wrong, so I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction for using these WCF services and a list of available entities that I can create in this manner, and how to create a new case/incedent entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a typo.

The name of the case entity is `incident` not `incedent`

Comment: Where can I find a list of all the entity names?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334400.aspx, on the left in the menu there are topics about different entities

Answer (score 2):

"incident" is misspelled in your example.  See if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well !, you should write the entity name as follows "incident" not "incedent"

and once you have the **Guid** of the record you can access it through the organization

service as follows:

```
//   To retrieve  all columns  from contact entity for example
ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet({ Allcolumns = true });
Entity retrievedIncident = OrgService.Retrieve("contact", id, cols);

//   To retrieve  specific columns 
ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(new String[] { "name", "address1_postalcode", "    lastusedincampaign", "versionnumber" });
Entity retrievedIncident = OrgService.Retrieve("contact", id, cols);
```